# No access to Android Market after loading Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: rom-flashing

I followed the instructions on the source.android.com website to download, build, and install Android OS v4.0.3 on a Nexus S. Everything seemed fine, I could take pictures, access WiFi to surf the web, etc. The problem is that there is no Market app and I have been unable to install anything via the Market over the web. The apps I had on the phone prior to loading ICS all show as "installed" on the website but they will not sync with the device. Any time I try to install a new app, everything seems to go ok and then it says the download will begin shortly but it never does. I have tried many different things described on posts such as resetting to factory defaults, clearing cache, etc but nothing works. Does anyone know how I can load the Market app or somehow download apps from the Market to manually install?

Comment: gapps do not come packaged with ROMs (or Android Source) due to licensing issues. For instance, when you usually flash a new mod (such as CyanogenMod), you flash the mod, then you flash the appropriate gapps zip file. See @eldarerathis's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you built the image yourself then Google's proprietary apps would not have been included as they are not open source. The easiest way to get them is probably to just use the CyanogenMod9 gapps package, which can be downloaded [here](http://goo-inside.me/gapps#table) (top of the table). If you have a custom recovery image then you can simply install the .zip file from your recovery, otherwise you'll have to manually install each of the files in the .zip (they have a folder structure that mimics your device).

The reason why the web Market isn't working is because it tries to use C2DM to push the app to the device, but this requires the Market app to be installed on the device. You cannot download the .apk from the Market manually.